# In MVC, how do I return a string result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, actionresult

In my AJAX call, I want to return a string value back to the calling page.

Should I use `ActionResult` or just return a string?

Comment: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30323853/2218697) to **return bootstrap alert message**

Answer (score 1184, accepted):

You can just use the [`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) to return a plain string:

```
public ActionResult Temp() {
    return Content("Hi there!");
}
```

[`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) by default returns a `text/plain` as its [contentType](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type). This is overloadable so you can also do:

```
return Content("<xml>This is poorly formatted xml.</xml>", "text/xml");
```

Comment: What is the contentType if your return type is a string?

Comment: I don't know how accurate this answer was back then, but currently `ContentResult` does `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType))` before setting `HttpContext.Response.ContentType`. I'm seeing `text/html` with your first example, either that's the default now or it's an educated guess by the `HttpContext`.

Comment: How can I Access in View ?

Comment: Small addition: instead of literally adding "text/plain" as a string, you could use a .NET framework constant like `MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain` or `MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml`. 

Although it only includes some of the most-used MIME types. _( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames )_

Comment: Up voted, though I did need to specify the mime type as "text/plain" when returning HTML as text per @Stijn comment.

Answer (score 118):

You can also just return string if you know that's the only thing the method will ever return. For example:

```
public string MyActionName() {
  return "Hi there!";
}
```

Comment: Phil, is this a "Best Practice", could you please explain the difference between the your answer and @swilliam 's

Comment: You can't return a string from a method which returns an ActionResult, so in this case you return Content("") as swilliams explained. If you only ever need to return a string, then you would have the method return a string, as Phil explained.

Comment: Assuming that same action has multiple `return` statements which are used to send either `string` or `JSON` or `View` based on conditions then we must use `Content` to return string.

Comment: What is the trick for the compiler to allow return type to be "string" if expecting IActionResult?

Answer (score 21):

```
public ActionResult GetAjaxValue()
{
   return Content("string value");
}
```

Comment: better to explain more during answer

Answer (score 6):

As of 2020, using [`ContentResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult.aspx) is still the right approach as proposed [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553952/2484903), but the usage is as follows:

```
return new System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult
{
    Content = "Hi there! ☺",
    ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There Are 2 ways to return a string from the controller to the view:

First

> You could return only the string, but it will not be included in your .cshtml file. it will be just a string appearing in your browser.

Second

> You could return a string as the Model object of View Result.

Here is the code sample to do this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    // this will return just a string, not html
    public string index()
    {
        return "URL to show";
    }

    public ViewResult AutoProperty()
    {   
        string s = "this is a string ";
        // name of view , object you will pass
        return View("Result", s);

    }
}
```

In the view file to run **AutoProperty**,  It will redirect you to the **Result** view and will send **s**
code to the view

```
<!--this will make this file accept string as it's model-->
@model string

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--this will represent the string -->
    @Model
</body>
</html>
```

> I run this at http://localhost:60227/Home/AutoProperty.

Answer (score 0):

```
public JsonResult GetAjaxValue() 
{
  return Json("string value", JsonRequetBehaviour.Allowget); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just return a string but some API's do not like it as the response type is not fitting the response,

```
[Produces("text/plain")]
public string Temp() {
    return Content("Hi there!");
}
```

this usually does the trick