# mvc 3 razor call a server side function using jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

i'm using this code to get a partial view from the server ot put it in a div

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyControler/MyAction",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#partialView').html(result);      
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("Coudn't load partial view");
        }
    });
```

now i would like to do the same thing but i'd call a simple methode returning a string and put the result in a textbox

```
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "MyControler/MyMethod",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#myTextBox').html(result);      
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("Coudn't load partial view");
        }
    });
```

the methode would be like that

```
    public string MyMethod()
    {
        returning "hello";
    }
```

obviously it doesn't work but is there a way to make it work ?? is there an attribute i should use for the methode

thanks in advance

ps:

from what i red in the first answer i tried this but it doesn't work

```
    public ActionResult Hello()
    {
        return Content("Hi there!");
    }
```

is there something wrong with the ajax call ??

```
$.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
         url: "MyControler/Hello",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#myTextBox').html(result);      
     },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert("Coudn't load partial view");
    }
});
```

ps

I wanted to try on a clean project and it worked fine using a simple method returning a string

since it worked i tried to implement it to my project but it seems it only works from the starting page set up in the global.asax file any idea what i should do to make it work in every pages ???

Answer (score 3):

You are making an **HttpPost** call. So make sure your Action method is decorated with `HttpPost` attribute. Also always try to use `Url.Action` HTML Helper method for the path to the action method.

The below code should work, assuming you have the `Hello` Action method present in `MMyControlerController`.

```
$.ajax(
        {
         type: "POST",
         url: "@Url.Action("Hello","MyControler")",
         success: function (result) {
             alert("result from server "+result);
             $('#myTextBox').html(result);      
         },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert("Coudn't load partial view");
        }
});
```

Your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hello()
{
  return Content("This is String Content");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess You should use following

```
$('#myTextBox').attr('value',result);
```

instead of

```
$('#myTextBox').html(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to return a string from that method, yes, but what you want is an ActionResult that returns the string
Check the following question and answer on StackOverflow.

[In MVC, how do I return a string result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553936/in-mvc-how-do-i-return-a-string-result)

Comment: from what i red i tried this but it doesn't work 
        public ActionResult Hello()
        {
            return Content("Hi there!");
        }

Comment: Please edit your question to when u need to paste code or make large changes

Comment: it doesn't help me cause i did just the same thins they said i think there is a probleme with the ajax call could you check please ?

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the `Url.Action` method for cases when you're running under a virtual directory or sub-domain. The Action method will create the correct Url.

Apart from that, it looks like you're POSTing to the site, so have you added the `HttpPost` attribute to your action?

Comment: could you please explain i'm not sure i understand what you mean

Comment: The `url: "MyController/MyAction"` lines, could use the Url.Action method like so `url: "@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")"`. If you're using an extension Javascript file, then simple embed/ generate the Url as a variable on the main page, and reference that via the external file.