# call server-side function from client-side in mvc3

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, callback

I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151667/mvc-3-razor-call-a-server-side-function-using-jquery), but the only thing that works from my solution is the error message alert. :D

My js-ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(function (e) {
        var data = { 'id': $(this).attr("id") };
        var dataVal = JSON.stringify(data);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")", 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataVal,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (id) {
                alert(data.d);
                alert("yay! it works!");
            },
            error: function(id){
                alert("haha, it doesn't work! Noob!");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It is located at the end of the body, so it loads after all the other html contents are rendered.

This is my call-back function in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Hello(string id)
{
    return RedirectToAction(id);
}
```

and the HTML anchor tag:

```
<a href="#" style="float:left; font-size:13px;" id="pageName">Read more</a>
```

So, what I want is, upon any click of an anchor tag link, this JS to be fired and calling the function from the server-side, passing to it the value of the *id* parameter, where the call-back function will do its job (which is to call some View, according to the given id).

Buuuuut, I am getting only "haha, it doesn't work! Noob!" alert message. :D Any suggestions ?

**Update with some code**
`RedirectToAction` is a method from the framework, that redirects to another action. In this case I redirect to an action that will call me a certain view, for example this one:

```
public ActionResult Media()
    {
        //do some stuff here 

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: This `$(document).ready(function () {});` itself is your guarantee that it will be executed just when the DOM is ready. You could place it anywhere you wanted, not just at the end of the page.

Comment: you should return `JsonResult`. What is `RedirectToAction(id)`? Show us code where you are redirecting.

Comment: This is not your problem, but it's wrong anyway: `success: function (id)`. It should be `success: function (data)`, as you're relying on it internally: `alert(data.d);`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK - still not working.

Comment: I didn't mean to post a solution. It was just another fix.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify you method

```
public ActionResult Media()
{
    //do some stuff here 

    return View();
}
```

to something like

```
public JsonResult Media()
{
    //do some stuff here 
    return Json(new
                {
                    myData = RenderPartialViewToString("ViewName", optionalModel),
                    errorMessage = error
                });
}
```

Add following method with reference to [ASP.NET MVC Razor: How to render a Razor Partial View's HTML inside the controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344533/asp-net-mvc-razor-how-to-render-a-razor-partial-views-html-inside-the-controll)

```
protected string RenderPartialViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        viewName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");

    ViewData.Model = model;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter()) {
        ViewEngineResult viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
        ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
        viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);

        return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, but why not a JsonResult instead of an ActionResult?

Comment: @MelanciaUK, cheers as `ActionResult` can handle `Json` thus left it. also updated answer