# asp.net mvc3: How to return raw html to view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, return

Are there other ways I can return raw html from controller? As opposed to just using viewbag. like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.HtmlOutput = "<HTML></HTML>";
        return View();
    }
}

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HtmlOutput)
```

Comment: I admit that there are lots of reasons to inject html directly, but I was curious why you were in this case?

Comment: I have some legacy code which generates markup from a dll.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

There's no much point in doing that, because `View` should be generating html, not the controller. But anyways, you could use [Controller.Content method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content.aspx), which gives you ability to specify result html, also content-type and encoding

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return Content("<html></html>");
}
```

Or you could use the trick built in asp.net-mvc framework - make the action return string directly. It will deliver string contents into users's browser.

```
public string Index()
{
    return "<html></html>";
}
```

In fact, for any action result other than `ActionResult`, framework tries to serialize it into string and write to response.

Comment: I agree with view generating html. my content thought is generated from a legacy dll. If the controller is not the right place to invoke, then maybe the model?

Comment: That is interesting about using a return type of string.  Has that always worked?

Comment: Yes. Anything that is not ActionResult is converted to string and returned response

Comment: Is there a way to return it as a `PartialViewResult`?

Comment: If you want to ensure it is rendered as html, add second parameter: `return Content("<html></html>", "text/html");`

Answer (score 8):

Simply create a  property in your view model of type MvcHtmlString. You won't need to Html.Raw it then either.

Comment: Thank you. Didn't use exactly what you said. What you said helped me figure out using [DataType.Html]

Answer (score 6):

Give a try to **return bootstrap alert message**, this worked for me

```
return Content("<div class='alert alert-success'><a class='close' data-dismiss='alert'>
&times;</a><strong style='width:12px'>Thanks!</strong> updated successfully</div>");
```

**Note:** Don't forget to add bootstrap `css` and `js` in your view page

hope helps someone.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me :)

Answer (score 5):

What was working for me (ASP.NET Core), was to set return type `ContentResult`, then wrap the HMTL into it and set the ContentType to `"text/html; charset=UTF-8"`. That is important, because, otherwise it will not be interpreted as HTML and the HTML language would be displayed as text.

Here's the example, part of a Controller class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Startup message displayed in browser.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>HTML result</returns>
[HttpGet]
public ContentResult Get()
{
    var result = Content("<html><title>DEMO</title><head><h2>Demo started successfully."
      + "<br/>Use <b><a href=\"http://localhost:5000/swagger\">Swagger</a></b>"
      + " to view API.</h2></head><body/></html>");
    result.ContentType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks fine, unless you want to pass it as Model string

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string model = "<HTML></HTML>";
        return View(model);
    }
}

@model string
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Html.Raw(Model)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult Questionnaire()
{
    return Redirect("~/MedicalHistory.html");
}
```

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer

Answer (score -2):

In controller you can use `MvcHtmlString`

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string rawHtml = "<HTML></HTML>";
        ViewBag.EncodedHtml = MvcHtmlString.Create(rawHtml);
        return View();
    }
}
```

In your View you can simply use that dynamic property which you set in your Controller like below

```
<div>
        @ViewBag.EncodedHtml
</div>
```