# Displaying twitter bootstrap alert after MVC4 form submit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple form in MVC 4.0, my project is based off the bootstrap3 for MVC4 VS2012 template. All I wish to do is have the user submit the form, then do some validations in my controller, and then based on what I pass back to the view, it should show a bootstrap alert(either error or success)

I have the form wired up so that it when I click Send it correctly fires the correct action on the controller. But I'm unsure about the following thing:

1. How do I hide the alert so it only shows after I return a result to the view.
2. I wish to display either an error or success alert, would I do this in jQuery, through .addClass?

![enter image description here][1]

[1]:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading"><strong>Register your interest</strong></div>
<p></p>

<div class="panel-body">

    <form name="contactform" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="/Home/Contact">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Comments</label><br />
            <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" rows="2" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; max-height: 350px; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p></p>

        <button id="myBtn" type="submit" value="send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button><p />


        <div class="alert alert-success" >             
            <strong>Thank you!</strong> Your query has been submitted. 
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: you want straight MVC validation.  It'll do exactly what you want, and it's built in.  You should research ViewModels

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30323853/2218697) to **return bootstrap alert message**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start by suggesting you research ViewModels as Jonesy suggests above, but to answer your question, a simple way (probably not the most elegant) is to set a ViewBag property in your controller for example like this:

```
... (code that validates data sent from view)
ViewBag.TheResult = true;
...
```

Then, change your view:

```
@if (ViewBag.TheResult == true) {
<div class="alert alert-success" >             
    <strong>Thank you!</strong> Your query has been submitted. 
</div>
}
```

This will make sure that the form only shows the alert if you validated the form successfully. Make sure you set the value of `TheResult` even if negative, because the view will be expecting to see that in the ViewBag.

As for your second question, you can resolve it in a similar way without JQuery by simply setting the value of the class in the ViewBag and using it in the markup.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up using knockout and JS.

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading"><strong>Register your interest</strong></div>
<p></p>

<div class="panel-body">

    <form name="contactform" class="form-inline" role="form" method="post" action="/Home/Contact">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Name</label>
            <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Email</label>
            <input type="email" data-bind="value: Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <p></p>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-info">Comments</label><br />
            <textarea data-bind="value: message" class="form-control" cols="20" rows="2" style="width: 400px; height: 150px; max-height: 350px; max-width: 500px"></textarea>
        </div>
        <p></p>

        <button id="mysubmit" type="submit" value="send" data-bind="click: btnCreateContact" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button><p />

        <div id="myalert" class="alert alert-success" hidden="hidden">
            <strong>Thank you! </strong> Your request has been submitted.
        </div>

        <div id="myalertError" class="alert alert-danger" hidden="hidden">
            <strong>Error! </strong>Please complete all fields.
        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

KNOCKOUT

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
var CreateContactVM = {

    Name: ko.observable(),
    Email: ko.observable(),
    message: ko.observable(),
    btnCreateContact: function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: urlPath + '/Contact',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                window.location.href = urlPath;
            },
            error: function (err) {
                if (err.responseText == "success") {
                    $('#myalertError').hide();
                    $('#myalert').show();
                    $('#mysubmit').prop('disabled', true);
                }
                else {
                    $('#myalert').hide();
                    $('#myalertError').show();                 
                }
            },
            complete: function () {
            }
        });

    }
};

ko.applyBindings(CreateContactVM);
```