# Pass list of objects jquery to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, checkbox

I have below code and need to pass it to my controller method on jQuery and read list of data on controller but have no idea to do it:

```
<p class="accounts form-inline">
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="accounts[0].IsSelected" value="true">ehsan.davodi<input type="hidden" name="accounts[0].AccountId" value="1"></label>
<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="accounts[1].IsSelected" value="true">e_davodi<input type="hidden" name="accounts[1].AccountId" value="2"></label>
</p>
```

Comment: Check this [link][1], about calling mvc action using jauery ajax.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11019392/1873002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you'll need to use a form to post the data. Something like in your View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... your form elements here ...
}
```

To do this with AJAX, you'll want to use `Ajax.BeginForm()`, of which you can read an example in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410055/using-ajax-beginform-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor).