# Using shared view in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, shared

I tried to add a shared view to `Views/Shared` folder which I need to return some plain text values in some cases. Here is my shared view `TextPlainView`:

```
@model string
@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
}
@Model
```

I tried to use it from a controller this way:

```
public ActionResult GetInfo(bool plain)
{
    //Some code to prepare data
    string result="Some data";
    if (plain)
        return View("TextPlainView", result);
    else
        return View(result);
}
```

I want to use this view across all controllers, so I want it to be shared.

I got this error:

> The view 'TextPlainView' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Orders/TextPlainView.aspx
>   ~/Views/Orders/TextPlainView.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/TextPlainView.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/TextPlainView.ascx
>   ~/Views/Orders/0.master
>   ~/Views/Shared/0.master
>   ~/Views/Orders/TextPlainView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Orders/TextPlainView.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/TextPlainView.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/TextPlainView.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Orders/0.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Orders/0.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/0.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/0.vbhtml

Comment: try this http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return plain text it would probably be better to use a [`ContentResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.contentresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). This is specifically for returning raw content without going through a view engine and by default it has a content type of `text/html`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/553952/493650 for more details.