# Retrieving Data from LINQ to SQL in JSON format?

Tags: c#, json, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with Serialization of Data from database to JSON format. I'm using WebAPI 2 and Entity Framework 6. I've created with EF a Model. The database and the tables with content are even created. 
When I use the code below I'm getting an error when I type http://localhost:54149/api/qr_group .

Controller:

```
private EfContext db = new EfContext();

// GET api/<controller>
public IEnumerable<QR_Group> GetGroups()
{
    var result = from g in db.QR_Groups
                 select g;
    return result.ToList();
}
```

I don't know how to use Newtonsoft.Json to serialize the table with the content in JSON format.

I've tried the following code instead of the code above:

```
public IQueryable<QR_Group> GetGroups()
{
  var groupList = (from g in db.QR_Groups
                   select new
                   {
                     name = g.name,
                     code = g.code
                   }).AsQueryable();

  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupList);

  return json; //error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to `System.Linq.IQueryable<RestApi.Models.QR_Group>'
}
```

I get the error CS0029.. How can I solve this to return the data in json? As reminder: The QR_Group entity has 3 columns (Id, name, code)

Comment: I don't know whether it can convert IQueryable to json string. try using .ToList() instead of AsQueryable() in the second function and also return string instead of IQueryable.

Comment: @Tanzeel .ToList() is not supported in IQueryable.. only in IEnumerable. But this I have also tried. But the problem is remained.

Answer (score 5):

Specifically to your second function, JsonConvert.SerializeObject would just serialize any object into a JSON format string, which means you should return a string instead of an IQueryable<>.

So for the controller there are quite a few ways to return it back, like: [In MVC, how do I return a string result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553936/in-mvc-how-do-i-return-a-string-result)

EDIT:

Following code would be one way that should working:

Controller:

```
private EfContext db = new EfContext();

// GET api/<controller>
public ActionResult GetGroups()
{
    var groupList = (from g in db.QR_Groups
    select new
    {
        name = g.name,
        code = g.code
    }).AsQueryable();

    return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groupList));
}
```

Comment: How can I solve my problem? Your link doesn't help me :(

Comment: The link is just about how to return a string as a controller, I've updated my answer by putting some code I think would work.

Answer (score 1):

> you didn't mention the error when you are returning list from the api
>   controller. as i assume that you are returning a database entity that
>   in simple case not allow you as json result, because your entity may
>   be linked with other entities in the database.

[you can check this link for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641386/failed-to-serialize-the-response-in-web-api)

Now modify your code to something like below. It is just to make you understand.

Define a Type say QR_Group_Return

```
public class QR_Group_Return{

    public string name{ get; set;}
    public string code{ get; set;}
    // Some other properties will go here.             
}
```

Now instead of returning `IEnumerable<QR_Group>` we will return `IEnumerable<QR_Group_Return>`

```
private EfContext db = new EfContext();

// GET api/<controller>
public IEnumerable<QR_Group_Return> GetGroups()
{
    var result = (from g in db.QR_Groups
                 select new QR_Group_Return {
                           name = g.name,
                           code = g.code,
                           // map your other properties also
                           }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps