# Content doesnt exists in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got a error (CS0103 C# The name 'Content' does not exist in the current context) in code below:

```
public ActionResult getsomething()
{
    var res = "something";
    return Content(res);}
```

Do u have any idea i can fix that?

Comment: What is Content? System.Web.UI.WebControls.Content?

Comment: You may have forget to include library or to perform the import, finally your line should be `return new Content(res);`

Comment: System.Web.UI.WebControls.Content - yes, it is.
None, return new Content(res); doesnt working.

Comment: What is res?
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Content does not have a Content(stirng value) constructor.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You can   return new Content().SamePropertyOfContnet = res;

Comment: [Code link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553952/5785572) In that case Content can work.

Comment: @Anamnian I got same error, figured out I had placed the method directly in a namespace instead of a controller class.

Comment: @prvn Try to ask another question, if green answer below question doesn't helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use  `System.Web.Mvc.Controller Content() function` instead `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Content Class`

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return Content("xxxxx");
        }
    }
}
```

Its work fine

========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: using static System.Web.Mvc.Controller;
public ActionResult getsomething()
        {
            var res = "something";
            return Content(res);
        }
 'Content' does not exist in the current context error

Comment: What assembly Version for System.Web.Mvc You use?

Comment: <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

Comment: does You see this row?
protected internal ContentResult Content(string content); protected internal ContentResult Content(string content, string contentType);

Comment: public string Content { get; set; }
    Member of System.Web.Mvc.ContentResult

Summary:
Gets or sets the content.

Returns:
The content.
Dont see any protected ContentResult.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: My bad, not used to ASP.NET. Will keep my previous answer for transparency

Seeing this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/553952/5785572), use `ContentResult` instead of `ActionResult`

```
public ContentResult getsomething()
{
    var res = "something";
    return Content(res);
}
```

---

Original post:

Did you try adding the `new` keyword ? Content is a class, thus need to be initialized.

```
public ActionResult getsomething()
{
    var res = "something";
    return new Content(res);
}
```

Comment: using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public ActionResult getsomething()
        {
            var res = "something";
            return new Content(res);
        }
It says 'Content' doesnt have a constructor that takes 1 argument

Comment: There is no need to initialise *Content* in the return statement.

Comment: Try to use `ContentResult` instead of `ActionResult`

[Solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/553952/5785572)

Comment: (Edit) Try use ContentResult, got this error: Non-invocable member 'Content' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: Did you remove the `new` and remove the `using` ? (I induced you in error, I'm sorry)

Comment: Sure.
public ContentResult getsomething()
        {
            var res = "something";
            return Content(res);
        }