# ASP.NET MVC - Modifying view result in OnActionExecuted

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC controller with a bunch of action methods returning ViewResult. Now, I need to be able to change the result of the action based on a certain URL parameter in the following way:

- If the parameter is not present, just return the `ViewResult` as it is
- If the parameter is present, take the `ViewResult` from the action that was just executed, render the view into a string, and return `FileStreamResult` containing this string (raw HTML) + some additional info (not relevant for the question)

I've tried to do this by overriding `OnActionExecuted` in my controller:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
    if (viewResult != null /* && certain URL param present*/)
    {
        string rawHtml = RenderViewIntoString(viewResult);
        filterContext.Result = new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawHtml)), "application/octet-stream");
    }
}
```

But I can't find a way to implement `RenderViewIntoString`, because for some reason `viewResult.View` is `null` here.

How can I render the view into a string here?

Comment: why don't you just return a string from your ActionResult?

Comment: @JordyvanEijk, because I have a lot of actions in my controller for which I need to implement the same logic. I want to have it all in one method.

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553936/in-mvc-how-do-i-return-a-string-result)

Comment: just make a method that does it all and call that method from every action. And have that method return something like a string or a ContentResult...

Comment: @JordyvanEijk, by "a lot" I mean 50+ methods. What you're suggesting is not very convenient. Is there no way to do it using action filters?

Comment: Well for starters you need to give some more information. Some code sample of your Controller and how you want to call your controller. If you can tell u that we maybe can find a way. Otherwise calling a method 50 times is better then something else because you have 50 Actions. But i doubt that 50 actions on 1 controller is normal. I never had so many action on one controller :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`viewResult.View` is filled only when the view result is executed in the context of a controller (see `ExecuteResult` method in [MVC source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ViewResultBase.cs)). The method `OnActionExecuted` is called earlier in the pipeline, that's why `viewResult.View` is `null` in your case.

What you need to do is manually find the view using `ViewEngineCollection` and then render it:

```
private static string RenderViewIntoString(ViewResult viewResult, ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    string viewName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewResult.ViewName) ? viewResult.ViewName : filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;

    IView view = viewResult.ViewEngineCollection.FindView(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, viewName, viewResult.MasterName).View;

    if (view == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"The view '{viewName}' or its master was not found");
    }

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var viewContext = new ViewContext(filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext, view, filterContext.Controller.ViewData, filterContext.Controller.TempData, stringWriter);
        view.Render(viewContext, stringWriter);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```