# Want to Serialize in specific format

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, jsonserializer

i want to serialize list object in following format.

1. without square bracket `[]`at start and end
2. without commma , it should be in new line.

   {"document_id":37577,"document_name":"Office Marketview........}
   {"document_id":37578,"document_name":"Office Marketview........}
   {"document_id":37579,"document_name":"Office Marketview........}
   {"document_id":37580,"document_name":"Office Marketview........}
   {"document_id":37581,"document_name":"Office Marketview........}

currently i am using

```
var jsoncontent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(publicationClasses, Formatting.None);
```

No idea. 
I google it, but not found any solution.

Comment: Since the format that you want to serialise to is not standard JSON, then it's maybe unwise to use a JSON serialiser - you may have to build your own.

Comment: @darasd i know that it is not valid format, but it is actually required due to some reason.

Comment: Why you don't replace what you don't want in the result string?

Comment: you might be looking for custom media type formatters.

Answer (score 1):

You could serialize each object independently and then perform a simple string-concat:

```
string result = string.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    publicationClasses.Select(obj => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None))
);
```

Use `\n` instead of `Environment.NewLine` if you so desire.

And then you can return the result as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553936/4205470) question as so:

```
return Content(result, "text/plain");
```

You can use the mimetype of your preference as required. Note that this is only a one-go solution, as mentioned in the comment section by *Amit Kumar Ghosh*, if this is something you need to be doing over and over all over the place then a custom media type formatter is the way to go (in fact, in order to adhere to the Web API practices, you should use a custom media formatter either way). However, this code provides the logic of it, you just need to perform the refactorings as necessary.